# How to enable Quick Access Wallet UI in Android 11

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement trivial quick access wallet pass - almost everything seem to be piece of cake (I'm following https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/quick-access-wallet) but this part: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/quick-access-wallet#wallet-ui

The article does not mention how to:

- include QuickAccessWallet target into the build - which config file should I modify and how? Guess that might be gradle question but really unsure here
- what is this overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/values/config.xml file and where should I place it? Is it supposed to be somehow added to my project?
- lastly - how to set default nfc payment app? They do mention def_nfc_payment_component there but not really saying where that's supposed to be set

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the code of `/cts/tests/quickaccesswallet/` for implementation of you payment application.

Just configure the file `/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/values/config.xml` for systemUI if you don't need overlay.

If there is only one payment app implemented with the article, then no need to configure `def_nfc_payment_component`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that still doesn't answer my question which is - where's that file? is that config.xml is supposed to be somewhere in source tree of my android app?

Comment: Ok, follow the mechanism in Google Docs, you should know that the wallet UI display requires the cooperation of system UI, wallet plugin and your payment application(except for other wallet implementations).

Your payment application is displayed in systemui globalActions(the window Long press the power button to show up) as plugin, and the property config_pluginWhitelist in config.xml you said is used to configure systemUI to enable plugin.

Comment: The plugin related to your quickaccess wallet here is com.android.systemui.plugin.globalactions.wallet.So where do you think config.xml is? It's an internal file of systemui, not in your app.